# Loading new data from a CSV file into an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, csv

I have an Excel spreadsheet which I made by

- starting with a CSV file
- converting the data into a table
- adding some columns to the table in which various computations happen
- saving the file as .xlsx

and I would now like to **replace the data with the contents of a new CSV file**. (Same column headings and interpretations, but different data in the rows.)

If I had had the wit to begin differently with "Get data" from the CSV file (in the Excel "Data" tab), then all would be well: I could overwrite that CSV file and tell Excel to refresh the query. (Perhaps there's a way to tell it to use a different CSV file instead, which would be even better. But this would be fine.)

Alas, I didn't do that. What I have now is a table whose left-hand portion is exactly the content of a CSV file I have, and which has some extra columns on the right, and I would like to update it so that the left-hand portion comes from a different CSV file (or the same one after modification, if for some reason that were easier), while the right portion does the same calculations as before.

I can't find a good way to do this. Is there one?

---

Some plausible-seeming approaches (spoiler: none of them seems much use; the last is the least-bad):

- There might be some functionality that just does what I want.

  - The obvious place to find it would be in the data importer that I should have used at the outset. This *does* give the option of importing into a table, and specifying a location within an existing worksheet. But if that location is in an already-existing table, Excel refuses to do it.
- It might be impossible to *replace* data in an existing table, but possible to *append* to it. In that case I could do that, and then delete the old rows.

  - The obvious thing to try is, again, the import-from-CSV operation, supplying the location immediately below the existing table. Unsurprisingly, though, that makes a new table.
  - If there were a way to *merge two adjacent tables*, perhaps that would do it? But I can't find one. (If you have two *queries* then you can "append" those but, again, the initial table was made by clumsier means and doesn't come from a query.)
  - There's [this relevant question](https://superuser.com/questions/1247921/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-csv-file-and-append-to-existing-excel-tabl) but so far as I can tell its only answer completely misses the point.
- There might be a way to split my table into two, one containing just the data that came from the CSV file and the other containing my other calculations, and then ... maybe there might be some simpler way of re-fetching the data, if I didn't have to worry about other stuff in the same table?

  - But I can't find a way to do that. There's a helpful-looking [Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/video-split-tables-5b72f010-6121-4b91-9011-120d66b000fb) about splitting tables ... but although it *says* "Excel for Office 365", it appears in fact to be only about tables in Word, which are entirely different.
  - And, in any case, I don't know of a way of reloading a table's data from a CSV file, even if there's nothing else in the table.
- Maybe I could load the new data into a *new* table, fix up the references in the *old* table's computational portion so that they refer to the new table, delete the old table's "data" columns, and move things around until the layout is convenient again.

  - But when I do this, structured references from one table to the other all yield `#VALUE!`. [This question and answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/value-error-for-structured-formula-reference/81be6cce-a87a-45f2-ab12-8813ba173237) on answers.microsoft.com suggests that such structured references only work right when the two tables occupy the same locations in the spreadsheet (albeit perhaps in different worksheet) -- this seems absurd, but experimentation suggests it might be true.
  - And it's rather laborious.
  - And [this question and its accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/450933/how-can-i-move-an-excel-table-to-a-different-worksheet) suggests that moving the new table to be back on the same sheet as the calculations based on it might turn out not to work if the amount of data is large (!).

---

This *seems* like a thing that ought to be easy. Am I missing something?

Comment: if this is a one off procedure, then import the CSV into a new table and then copy and paste values into the CSV data section of your other file. The formulas should work. A longer term solution would be to use the Data->from CSV functionality

Comment: Ha, that does seem like a simpler and better approach than the more complicated ones I mentioned...